# Using the return value of a contract function in another function

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-design, contract-invocation

I have a smart contract **A** with a public function **a1** that can be called by anyone and this public function will return a **uint** value based on another public function named **a2** inside the same contract **A**.

Function **a1**:

```
function calculateReputation(string memory sender_string) public payable returns
(uint) {
address _sender = parseAddr(sender_string);
if (totalShipped[_sender] != 0) {
return (100 * successShipped[_sender] / totalShipped[_sender]);
}
else {
return 0;
}
}
```

I also have a secondary contract **B** with a public function **b** which requires the **uint** value returned by the **a1** function inside contract **A**.

Function **b**:

```
function addSupplier(string memory _name, uint _phoneNo, string memory
_cityState, string memory _country, string memory _goodsType) public payable returns (bool success)
{
// don't overwrite existing entries and ensure name isn't null
if (bytes(suppliers[msg.sender].name).length == 0 &&
bytes(_name).length != 0) {
    
// address _sender = parseAddr(msg.sender);  
string memory msg_string = toAsciiString(msg.sender);
    
suppliers[msg.sender].name = _name;
suppliers[msg.sender].phoneNo = _phoneNo;
suppliers[msg.sender].cityState = _cityState;
suppliers[msg.sender].country = _country;
suppliers[msg.sender].goodsType = _goodsType;
suppliers [msg. sender].reputation = track.calculateReputation(msg_string);
suppliersByAddress.push(msg.sender);
return true;
}
else {
return false; // either entry already exists or name entered was null
}
}
```

Running through the debugger, the issue comes to the REVERT() inside of function **b**, when I use *track.calculateReputation(msg_string)* to call for the value returned by function **a1**. The error is the following:

[image]

I do not wish to send ETH or wei, so I do not quite understand how this issue should be solved. I made all the functions involved *payable*, even making the constructor of the **A** contract *payable*, but it did not seem to solve the issue.

I would definitely appreciate at least some insight in this issue.

Comment: Please only include relevant code. Having excessive code makes analysis a lot harder

Comment: I have removed the definitions of the contracts themselves, leaving only the two respective functions that present the problem, namely **a1** and **b**.

Comment: I suggest you remove lines/functionality until you figure out which part causes the revert, then it's easier to think of what might be wrong.